# How to declare an element with only attributes in a XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Given:

```
<authentication password="turkey" partnerid="exam" />
```

how can I declare this element in a XML schema?

I have got:

```
<xs:element name="authentication" type="auth_type" />

<xs:complexType name ="auth_type">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="password" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="partnerid" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

but it will allow the element to have text content, will it? I do not want that...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can remove the `xs:simpleContent` and `xs:extension`....

```
  <xs:element name="authentication" type="auth_type" />

  <xs:complexType name ="auth_type">
    <xs:attribute name="password" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="partnerid" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: @Mirko - In your example you had to use `xs:extension` to extend `xs:simpleContent` and `xs:simpleContent` is what allowed text to be in your element.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a complex element, for example:

```
<product prodid="1345" />
```

The "product" element above has no content at all. To define a type with no content, we must define a type that allows elements in its content, but we do not actually declare any elements, like this:

```
<xs:element name="product">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:attribute name="prodid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

check http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_empty.asp